# Loop through all sites in multisite installation

Tags: templating, craft3, multi-site

Who knows how to loop through all sites in multisite installation? I want to create kind of drop down menu to switch between websites.
I've found this code inside the backend template but looks like it doesn't works in frontend

```
{% for site in allSites %}
            <tr data-id="{{ site.id }}" data-name="{{ site.name|t('site') }}">
                <th scope="row" data-title="{{ 'Name'|t('app') }}"><a href="{{ url('settings/sites/' ~ site.id) }}">{{ site.name|t('site') }}</a></th>
                <td data-title="{{ 'Handle'|t('app') }}"><code>{{ site.handle }}</code></td>
                <td data-title="{{ 'Language'|t('app') }}"><code>{{ site.language }}</code></td>
                <td data-title="{{ 'Base URL'|t('app') }}"><code>{{ site.baseUrl }}</code></td>
                {% if multiple %}
                    <td class="thin"><a class="move icon" title="{{ 'Reorder'|t('app') }}" role="button"></a></td>
                    <td class="thin"><a class="delete icon" title="{{ 'Delete'|t('app') }}" role="button"></a></td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

UPD:
Now I can fetch names of websites by their Ids:

```
      {% set allSitesIds = craft.app.sites.getAllSiteIds() %}
  {% for site in allSitesIds %}
  {% set siteName = craft.app.sites.getSiteById(site) %}
  {{siteName}}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this purely from a template, then something like this:

```
{% set sites = craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}

{% for site in sites %}
    <li>{{ site.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

In Craft 3, `craft.app` in a template basically gives you access to everything in the [`services`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/develop/src/services) namespace.  Adding `craft.app.sites` opens up all of the methods in [`services/Sites.php`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/services/Sites.php)

Answer (score 4):

Nikolay,

As I responded in the slack, I will respond here in case anyone else has this question.

In the template you can access this information like so:

```
SiteUrl: {{ siteUrl }}
Langauge: {{ craft.app.language }}
Handle: {{ craft.app.sites.currentSite.handle }}
```

I'm not entirely positive how to loop the sites in the template but you can get a sites object in PHP by running the following in a controller somewhere or in the `init()` method of any plugin that is installed:

```
$sites = Craft::$app->getSites();
var_dump($sites);
exit;
```

This will output the structure of the sites object. Baring this you can look through the craft source / docs to find the details on the site object that returns. There should be a method for getting sites by id or by handle; `$sites->getSitesByID()` or `$sites->getSitesByHandle()` but I have not double checked this so you'll have to try it or look it up. If there is not a method then it should be accessible via an array property like `$sites->sitesByHandle` or `$sites->byHandle`. Again you'll have to double check on this.

By the way, that functionality should translate to the template version of the sites object `craft.app.sites` so you should be able to do:

```
{% set sites = craft.app.sites.getSitesByHandle() %}
```

Or something like that anyway.

Once you figure it out feel free to update this to reflect the proper methods / properties :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a script in order to save different credentials for each site in my google analytics plugin.
So I had to render a dropdown to chose the site as well. Here is my code

First the Plugin variable. You could actually remove the most and just return the `sites` variable

```
public function getSites(){
    $response = [];
    $sites = Craft::$app->sites->getAllSites();
    // I had some permission checks here as well to see if the user 
    // has access to the site, but I removed that in this example
    foreach($sites as $site){
        $response[] = array(
            "label" => $site->name,
            "value" => $site->id
        );
    }
    return $response;
}
```

And this is my template.

```
{% set sites = craft.googleanalytics.getSites() %}
{% set siteId = entry.lnkSiteId? entry.lnkSiteId : sites[0]["value"] %}
{{ forms.selectField({
    label:          'Seite'|t,
    id:             'lnkSiteId',
    name:           'lnkSiteId',
    instructions:   'Bitte wählen Sie die Seite'|t,
    value:          siteId,
    options:        sites
}) }}
```